# Do we say "Now the prince is still bewitched" or "Now the prince is under a spell" to express the current state?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, adjectives, phrase-choice

We say "**The dog scared me 1 hour ago and now I am still scared**".

We have the verb "**to scare**" and the adjective "**scared**".

But it seems we can not apply that usages for all verbs.

For example, we say **I opened the door 1 hour ago and now the door is still open**, but not **I opened the door 1 hour ago and now the door is still opened**.

**We don't know when the participle of a verb can be used as an adjective**

Why the participle "**opened**" can not be used as an adjective?

For example,

**Can we say?**

"**The witch bewitched the prince 1 hour ago and now the prince is still bewitched**" or

"**The witch bewitched the prince 1 hour ago and now the prince is still under a spell**"?

Comment: did you mean "still bewitched".  YOu wrote "till" in the last two examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open is ergative, so the participle form has a particular sense of implying an actor.  To describe the state of the door you can use the (related) adjective "open"

Contrast "An open door" with "An opened door".  Both are correct, but the second implies the existence of an opener.

But "bewitch" isn't ergative.  We can't say "she bewitches" in the way that we can say "the door opens".  So their is no problem with the particle form "she is bewitched", and this is the normal expression. "Bewitched" functions as an adjective.

You can also use a synonym like "under a spell". That is your choice.